# Sharing large pictures with a facebook application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, image

How do I share a big picture from an application?

We have an application with a trivia quiz, but we can only share small pictures.

Is it possible to share a picture at the original size?

here is the link for testing the apps:

https://www.facebook.com/LeChampionDeBlueExorcistCommunity?sk=app_374441249291232

Comment: Which APIs are you currently using to share the photos? Have you looked at Open Graph publishing with user generated photos or the photos API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Open Graph to share stories with (large) user generated action photos.

The documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/

Something like this will work, in conjunction with an Open Graph action post.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/yournamespace:cook?
  recipe=http://www.yourdomain.com/pizza.html&
  image[0][url]=http://www.yourdomain.com/images/my_camera_pizza_pic.jpg&
  image[0][user_generated]=true
```

You can also post a photo to a user's albums using the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/ API

Which you choose to use partly depends on the use case you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's perfetct :)

Comment: hi again , the technique you have give to me work for me as admin of the application , but when i use the open graph test user i see the photo posted on a album but not on the user timeline and I also have a problem with the validation of my open graph action with the user generated picture Fb response is "I'am not using well this function" . Thanks a lot for your help and pleas excuse my English