# I can't make the photos bigger after posting using my photo posting app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I have an app created for FB which was supposed to upload a photo in profiles and pages. The concept is, if someone clicks the photo, it will redirect to another website. It was successful.

However, I want to make the photo bigger just like in a regular photo upload. After uploading the photo, it will appear as an article post/share and not the photo upload that has a bigger size. How can I make the photo bigger. How can I make it look like as photo upload and not article upload?

I was told that this is not possible. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not much about bigger photos post on Facebook but find below links which will help you,

1. [How to get large photo URL in one API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599638/how-to-get-large-photo-url-in-one-api-call)
2. [How to get the large picture from feed with graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527530/how-to-get-the-large-picture-from-from-feed-with-graph-api)
3. [Facebook Graph API : get larger pictures in one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650730/facebook-graph-api-get-larger-pictures-in-one-request)
4. [Sharing large pictures with a facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142740/sharing-large-pictures-with-a-facebook-application)
5. [facebook graph api - post large image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512409/facebook-graph-api-post-large-image)

Let me know, which link will help you the most?